# Windows IOT Getting error when deploying related to connecting

Tags: iot, windows-iot-core-10

I have two Rasberry-pi devices. I installed Windows 10 IOT in that, but there are a couple of issues I am having.

1. The first issue i got when I try to connect the Rasberpi with VS2019 to deploy my app is giving this error

   Severity Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
           Error       DEP6100: The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '192.168.1.16'.': FileLoadException - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Tools.Connectivity, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A) [0x8013141A] App13
   [image]

[image]

2. My devices are showing on the IoT dashboard and able to open browser it is working.
3. The issue I am having when trying to remote the client just showing black screen

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have not encountered this error before. Please confirm if the tool is installed. This component is used for cross platform deployment. Or you may try to to reinstall the visual studio 2019.
[image]

From Windows IoT Core 16299, the Windows IoT Remote client does not work for Raspberry Pi.It is known issue on [Release note](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/release-notes/commercial/fallcreatorsupdate#known-issues).

**Update:**

I have tried to find out the Microsoft.Tools.Connectivity. It exists in folder C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\bin\10.0.18362.0\x86. Please make sure you have installed the correct version of Windows Kits. Please download the sdk here.

[enter link description here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk/)

Comment: Connectivity and publish tools are installed, i reinstall the VS2019 still getting this issue --->>>>>>"Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error  DEP6100: The following unexpected error occurred during bootstrapping stage 'Connecting to the device '192.168.1.15'.': FileLoadException - Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Tools.Connectivity, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. Strong name validation failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8013141A) [0x8013141A] App15"

Comment: Which version of Windows IoT Core is on your device? And which target version and min version of your project?

Comment: Raspberry Pi3 OS version :10.0.17763.107 @Michael Xu -MSFT

Comment: Visual Studio Target version : 18362   min Version : 17763

Comment: @ZCoder, i have updated the repsonse. Please feel free let me it is helpful for you.